# Scala: how to filter a RDD with wildcard

Tags: scala, rdd

How to filter a RDD with wildcard (* and ?) by doing something like:

```
val filtered_rdd = rdd.filter(x => x.SomeField.contains(*abc??))
```

Is there a way to realize this in Scala and with RDD; namely, not to use python or DataFrame.

Comment: What is the type of `someField` what do you mean with wildcard in this case? What have you tried?

Comment: The type of SomeField is simply string in my case. I am a newbie with scala; and trying the "code" above simply results 0 record because the "contains" simply takes the literal meaning of "*" and "?".

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the `contains` method? It says that it checks if  the string contains the other, so it already behaves like a wildcard _(for that reason the method has the intuitive name of contains, not equals)_. So yeah it is taking into account the literal meaning of the asterisk and the quotation mark. If you need to check against a more complex pattern rather than a whatever-something-whatever, you would need to use a regex.

Comment: Thank you Luis! You comment is helpful!

Comment: If you do need a regex, I would suggest you to update your question providing more details about what are your concrete requirements. If not, and the problem was just the misuse of contains then I would suggest you to close the question, since it falls under the category of _"simple typographical error"_.